# How do I check if a variable isnt defined, throw an error that shows me which variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement

I am trying to look if a variable is defined / got an actual object in it, and if not, show me which var doesnt have it.

```
var $a= $('.a'),
    $b= $('.b'),
    $c= $('.c');

if ( $a, $b, $c ) /* maybe use .length? and if so, can I use it like this 
                   * ($a, $b, $c).length == 0 ? but like, I need to check every variable once alone! when $a is 3 times present, do not stop here, go on the $b and check if that is == 0... */
  alert('No' + $showMeWhichVariable + ' found');
```

I hope you get what I am trying to do.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can just loop and check :

var elms = ['.a', '.b', '.c'],
    errors = '';

for (var i = 0, len = elms.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (!$(elms[i]).length) {
        errors += '<li>' + elms[i] + 'doesn\'t exist</li>';
    }
}

$('ul').append(errors).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables will not be "undefined". When called with a selector the `$()` function will always return a jQuery object, with a `.length` property indicating how many elements matched the selector - if none matched `.length` will be 0.

elclanrs answer shows how to use a loop to test whether any elements match your three selectors, but assuming you already have a variable such as your `$a`, that was created with `$a = $(".a")` then you can test whether the jQuery object referenced by that variable is empty as follows:

```
if ($a.length === 0) {
    // no elements matched, so do something
}
```

Note that you can call jQuery methods on an empty jQuery object without getting an error, so something like:

```
$a.hide();
```

Will hide any and all elements that matched the selector used to create `$a` but if no elements matched (`.length===0`) nothing happens - there are no ill effects. You don't have to test `.length` first.

Comment: you're right, but If I want to know, why $a.hide() doesnt work and dont want to search through the code, I can just give myself an error with the variable that isnt set :)
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var object ={};
object['$a'] = $('.a');
object['$b'] = $('.b');
object['$c'] = $('.c');

$.each(object, function(key,value){
    if(!object[key]) alert("No "+key+" Found");
});
```

Comment: You need to say `if (object[key].length === 0) ...` as explained in my answer. Or, better, `if (value.length === 0) ...` - why use the `$.each()` function and then ignore the `value` parameter that is already set to `object[key]`?